# Postgres cursor multiple app server readers

Tags: postgresql, cursor, shared

I'm trying to spread the load of processing millions of records onto multiple application servers. The records are created by means of a complex join. That is the data cannot simply be retrieved from one table. Our idea is to use a cursor, and it's working with one application server that does the complex calculations. Now we want to add one or more servers to speed up processing. Any idea how to do that? How to share the cursor among multiple readers deployed on separate (application) servers? Our app logic is python based and we are using psycopg2.

thanks a lot for your help

Juergen

Answer (score 1):

A PostgreSQL database connection and a query result delivered in such a connection cannot be shared between multiple clients.

Either you come up with several `SELECT` statements, each of which returns part of the result, or you have to retrieve them on one client and pass result rows around between the application servers.